# android - image quality is low when using glide

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I'm new to android developing. In my app, I have a `horizontalScrollView` that contains images. Later I have been using Picasso to load images from URL. Then I heard about glide so I switched to glide and now my image loading is fast but the quality of images is too low.

code below

```
//load image from URL 1.1
        ivImageFromURL = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.videoconwmimage);
        Glide.with(this).load("http://imgur.com/KtfpVUb.png").into(ivImageFromURL);
```

Comment: Looks like your image is not high resolution image

Comment: when I'm using picasso the image looks fine...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you are using Glide v4, then when making Glide requests, change

```
Glide.with(imageView).load(url).into(imageView);
```

to

```
Glide.with(imageView).load(url)
    .apply(new RequestOptions()
            .fitCenter()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL))
    .into(imageView);
```

That did the trick for me without having to add anything to the manifest. It might help to also add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView` in XML. The classes are

```
import com.bumptech.glide.load.DecodeFormat;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target;
```

Comment: I success with just `override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)`. Why you call `fitCenter()` and `format()`? And I success with just `dontTransform()` too.

Comment: this one fixed my problem.

Comment: Perhaps we should use `dontTransform()` instead of `fitCenter()`? - https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/531#issuecomment-120012741

Comment: Thanks a lot for `.override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)`.

Answer (score 2):

> This is because Glide default Bitmap Format is set to RGB_565 since it
>   consumed just 50% memory footprint compared to ARGB_8888 used by Picasso.

you can fix it making following changes:

```
public class GlideConfiguration implements GlideModule {

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        // Apply options to the builder here.
        builder.setDecodeFormat(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
        // register ModelLoaders here.
    }
}
```

And add following to your manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.inthecheesefactory.lab.glidepicasso.GlideConfiguration"
            android:value="GlideModule"/>
```

For more details visit [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link

**Glide loads with lower image quality**

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1227

Answer (score 0):

Glide uses RGB_565 not to use too much memory. If defaults dont seem fine to you, you can use Glide.Builder and set `builder.setDecodeFormat(DecodeFormat.ALWAYS_ARGB_8888);` as your preferred configuration.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration check the link.